# AngularJS, Directive improvement

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I wrote my very first directive and I'd like to get some suggestions for improvement.
My code - [plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/NW5VPl2anBThpnvOZiSD?p=preview)

```
webApp.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.expandAdd = function() {
    $scope.hiddenAdd = true;

};

$scope.addWeb = function() {
    $scope.hiddenAdd = false;
};


});


webApp.directive('enter',function(){
return {

    link: function (scope, element, attrs){

        scope.hiddenAdd = false;   //hides the site details at first
        //Invoke expender on the controller on mouse click
        element.bind('click', function(){
            console.log('clicked');
            scope.$apply(attrs.enter);
        });
    }
}
});
```

I have three points I think I can improve here but I'm not sure how:

1. My directive is not modular enough, the line `scope.hiddenAdd = false` is bound to `hiddenAdd`. Is it possible to make it more flexible for future use? 
   Though it seems two be picking to different `bindings` I think that is because they are both start with `hidden`.
2. Inside the `controller` I'm doing `DOM` manipulation  `$scope.hiddenAdd = true;` & `$scope.hiddenAdd = false;` from what I've read it all best be inside `directives` and I can't find the way to make it a pure `directive`.
3. I read somewhere that it is not recommended to use `$apply` too often, is there a way to avoid using `apply` in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: Don't use a directive.**
What you are trying to do does not actually require a directive. It is simple enough to play with the scope.

```
  $scope.expandAdd = function() {
    $scope.hiddenAdd = true;
  };

  $scope.addWeb = function() {
    $scope.hiddenAdd = false;
  };
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VqEatAKJ4wGTdmzSAxE2?p=preview)